# Finding tutoring in Maths / CS

Tags: self-learning, struggling-students

I am technically enrolled on a university course but lack basic maths ability and have fallen behind in trying to catch up. Therefore I need to explore self-learning to improve my position while continuing my university course.

I'm looking for a math / computer science tutor to cover areas of discrete maths; number theory / proofs and counting plus others. Other suggestions for helping me come up to speed in these areas might also be helpful.

I'm a mature student and am keen to put the hours of work that are needed. I have some materials but there aren't enough examples provided to help me to understand better.

How does one find tutoring and other supplemental aid for otherwise engaged students in these areas? Does online tutoring exist?

Comment: I'd need more practical examples of the maths tasks you'll need to do, equations, statistics, 2D/3D graphs and so forth. I learnt all my maths by programming graphs, because you change variables and you get instant feedback for your input. If you can find a colorful image generation program, it's good to do some images. FooPlot is very basic. you should know how to write sines/cosines/and change their amplitudes and frequencies and also graph squares/powers. My own self learnign of maths was 1/making birdsongs and synths on Reaktor 5 builder, 2/Milkdrop for winamp making images 3/Unity3D

Comment: I can give you a pdf of the course book thst Twente provided, there are problem sets on the end of each chapter. Also Guided problem sets and the old exams

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this isn't a perfect answer since it *may* lack the personal contact with an instructor that may be the most valuable. However [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org) has a number of courses that might provide the necessary background if you can match their schedule.

In particular [Combinatorics and Probability](https://www.coursera.org/learn/combinatorics) should teach you sophisticated counting techniques.

They also have a series of courses on [Discrete Math for Computing](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/discrete-mathematics) that probably covers the rest. (Combinatorics is one of the courses in this sequence.)

The downside, however, is that you don't get much in the way of a personal touch that you get in a face-to-face environment.

Some of the various online course sites provide some tutorial help and more provide peer-to-peer contact, but the quality of the help you get with that is likely spotty. It may help you get over some of the humps, but will be less valuable for building mathematical insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you visited [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) website. I was just like you. My math skills were very poor. This website helped me to raise it to same level of my classmates at college. Its totally free forever.

This is a link for [Number Theory](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-BD05SCClbag8KTPzaPzzggJ96aBsVkT) I could not find the link to the khanacademy website, Its a link of their youtube playlist.

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]! Could you make this answer a little more detailed? I was not aware that Khan Academy covered much discrete math, but a link to relevant sections would be very helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @BenI. Thanks for the feedback. I was talking about basic math skills as he mention in his question. For Discrete Math dunno if it has a branch dedicated to it, I never searched for it. But Im sure they have something on Number theory I will put the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I received a lot of suggestions from this site a few weeks back and wanted to pop back to update you all. 
The Kemeny book is fantastic, although how things have changed in terms of phrasing, examples and general presentation (!!). Its been very helpful though. 
Random but I came across this, a receipt left in the book - dated from 1965, as you can see its in old money too. It had had actually marked the page, it had been there so long. The book was posted to me from the US but I guess its been awhile since this book has been opened. [Very old book](https://i.imgur.com/lzWFjuC.jpg)

Comment: Jenny, thanks for checking back in, and glad to know we helped you! Could you integrate some of this information into the question or into comments on the question? While very lovely, this isn't an answer.